# How to move block generated by magento extensions in the layout?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

We're using a magento extension to deal with back to stock notifications (Ebizmarts MageMonkey). This is generating a block in our product pages, when the product is out of stock.

Problem is, the block end up at the end of the main column of the product page, when we would like it to be in the right column of the page.

So, the question is, **is there a clean way to move where a block generated by a magento  extension (be it MageMonkey or any other) is displayed in a page WITHOUT changing the extension code ?** Is there something i can do with a layout.xml file to change where it display, or is it tied to the extension itself ?

I'm still a beginner with magento, so i may be missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable your template path hints. To do this go to

System --> Configuration --> Developer --> Set template path hints to yes.

If you refresh the page you will see red blocks around your layout components. Find the lay-out block  you want to move and open the file (probably a .phtml file). In there you will find something like this:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my-block')->toHtml();
```

Cut out that piece of code and place it anywhere you want it.

Comment: Finally found out where it was with the path hint. Thank you very much !